Fixing drywall paper damage
I’m working on some renovations in my kitchen and there is some serious drywall damage beside where the old cabinet was.
I am wanting to permanently remove the cabinet and want to fix the wall to be smooth for painting. I have been reading a lot online and see that most people recommended applying an oil sealant and mudding where torn drywall is. I guess my mind is mentally struggling with the fact that there are three levels of surface here:

Painted wall
Exposed drywall
Damaged drywall

In simplest terms, how can I get a smooth wall to prepare for repainting?



Also How to fix ripped drywall before repaint, Can drywall with ripped paper be repaired?, How can I finish this "peeled" drywall?,  How do I fix drywall damaged by peeling paint tearing off the outer paper?, How can I repair ripped plasterboard paper and What might be a good way to fix this damaged drywall?

@isherwood I instantly disregarded the posts without images, but I looked at all of those posts before hand. One was a large area of damage but had no paint around it- only good vs torn drywall. Another had large damage and paint, but there was severe bubbling and the wall itself was not in good condition. Two others were small damage so I felt like the answer for drywalling could be much different. I think this post also has better images than others. Let me know if you agree.

@bboan, the general technique (scrape, seal, mud, prime) works on damage more extensive and surfaces more uneven than yours. Ultimately, you'll cover the damaged area with a smooth, 1/8" thick-or-so layer of mud bringing the damaged area flush and extending into the painted area. Multiple layers make no difference. They'll all be covered with mud.  If you don't hire a pro, getting a good result as an amateur will take tools, technique, and time. I suggest watching lots of YouTube videos. I've found the Vancouver Carpenter helpful.

If you do not want to replace the drywall (which is what I recommend) then you can seal the paper and damage using Gardz (no affiliation I just think it's a uniquely suitable product) then potentially sand, skim coat, and prime (or apply Gardz again).

I hadn't heard of Gardz.   I looked it up.  It sounds like a good alternative to replacing the board.  The next time I have the same situation I will try it.

Thanks for your advice! Does this mean that I would be applying mud to make it even with the paint of the surrounding wall?

@bboan I suspect the Gardz will only seal the area, and you'll need to skim coat the wall with mud to even it out.  Which is probably why RMDman recommends simply replacing the drywall—it's easier to smooth out just the joints than the whole field.

Essentially you are doing plaster work which is a skill that generally takes a while to learn.  The other challenge to that is you are likely going to end up with a different texture than the undamaged drywall. An 'orange-peel' mud spray can resolve that, but it's more work and another art. A matte or flat finish will make it less apparent as well.

Sometimes when the damage is as bad as some areas showing your pictures I have resorted to removing large sections of the damaged areas completely back to the studs and then fitting in new replacement drywall. If you do this it can be possible to not even have to cut back to the center of a stud. Instead you can add backing in the form of flat lengths of wood that are positioned along the edges of the existing drywall and the replacement drywall and screwed into place.
